# Why did Jung Chung leave Lee Ja-sung in New World?

Tags: plot-explanation, new-world

In *New World* Jung Chung found 3 moles (*rats, they call in that movie*), one of them is Ja-sung himself. But Jung leaves Ja-sung behind. Why?

Note that I knew that Jung trusted Ja-sung to call him his brother. Is that all to relieve him? I thought he would be killed when there is his profile in the list.

Comment: I haven't recently watched it, but as far as I recall it came off something like The Departed when Costello's gang member didn't reveal Billy was the rat. He didn't want to be responsible for his death on his deathbed.